# Does Watch Dogs multiplayer require Gold?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network, watch-dogs

I'm thinking of purchasing Watch(_)Dogs for my Xbox 360, but I don't have Gold. Does the multiplayer aspect of the game require Xbox Live Gold?

Comment: Any in game online function requires gold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xbox 360 games require Xbox Live Gold in order to play online with other players. If you try to play Watchdogs online without Gold it will tell you that you have *insufficient online privileges to continue*.